# Changing java service wrapper conf file property inside a pom

Tags: maven, java-service-wrapper

I'm using java service wrapper in a project and want to change **wrapper.logfile.maxsize**
property of the wrapper.conf file.The thing is that it would be better if I can change it inside **maven pom.xml** file. So can anyone please tell me whether this is possible and if so how to do it ?

Thanx...

Comment: Are you using some kind of plugin for JSW ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Maven Resource Plugin's Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) feature. Let's say the line that needs to be configured by Maven looks like

```
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=500
```

Replace it with:

```
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=${wrapper.logfile.maxsize}
```

add filtering in the `project/build/resources/resource/` section with:

```
<filtering>true</filtering>
```

and populate the right value from command line:

```
mvn resources:resources -Dwrapper.logfile.maxsize="500"
```