# What maven 3.0.4 pom will write a dependency artifact including version into a Tanuki Service Wrapper conf file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, java-service-wrapper

IS there a way to get Maven 3.0.4 to output a dependency artifact's name and version into a text resource?

A specific use case is: The Tanuki Service Wrapper (wrapper.exe) supports launching a Java Virtual Machine process (java.exe) configured by a text file (.conf file) that contains lines like

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=./somejar1
wrapper.java.classpath.2=./somejar2
wrapper.java.classpath.3=./somejar3
```

We're using the maven-assembly-plugin to create a distribution zip for artifact X that will contain a Tanuki wrapper.exe .conf file.  We need the .conf file's classpath entries to contain all the dependencies of X.  For example, X depends on log4j.  We would like Maven to update the .conf file to be something like

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=./log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

The closest stackoverflow answer I've found is
[Changing java service wrapper conf file property inside a pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767522/changing-java-service-wrapper-conf-file-property-inside-a-pom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever taken a look into the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) ? Depending on version your are using of the Tanuku Service Wrapper ? in Particular http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-jsw.html

Comment: But the appassembler plugin is stuck on version 3.2.3. If you wan to use it with a later version of Tanuki you have to start unpacking the tar and it all gets so messy

Comment: The problem is simply the license of newer JSW versions.

Comment: I agree but even if you purchased a licence I would say its no longer compatable with Maven. Sure you can get around it but Tanuki have no out of the box maven integration from 3.2.3. Would you agree with that?